# Onclick text populates both textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of textareas and when I click on a paragraph outside the text is supposed to be added to the textarea, it works but the text is also getting added to the textareas above.

I'm a bit stumped on why this is happening and as I have 10 textaraes so clicking a paragraph at the bottom of the page adds the text to all the other textareas above.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#PollutionPreventionDivScrollDisplay").hide();

    $("#PollutionPreventionDivScroll").on("click", function () {
        $("#PollutionPreventionDivScrollDisplay").toggle();
    });

    var cartlist = document.querySelector("#EnvironmentalActionPollutionPreventionIdeasForAction");
    var items = document.querySelectorAll("[data-item]");

    [].forEach.call(items, function (item) {
        item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            cartlist.value += `\n${item.innerHTML}`;
        });
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#WasteDivScrollDisplay").hide();

    $("#WasteDivScrollDisplayScroll").on("click", function () {
        $("#WasteDivScrollDisplay").toggle();
    });

    var cartlistOne = document.querySelector("#EnvironmentalActionWasteManagementIdeasForAction");
    var itemsOne = document.querySelectorAll("[data-item]");

    [].forEach.call(itemsOne,
        function (itemOne) {
            itemOne.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                cartlistOne.value += `\n${itemOne.innerHTML}`;
            });
        });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#EnergyDivScrollDisplay").hide();

    $("#EnergyDivScrollDisplayScroll").on("click", function () {
        $("#EnergyDivScrollDisplay").toggle();
    });

    var cartlistTwo = document.querySelector("#EnvironmentalActionEnergyIdeasForAction");
    var itemsTwo = document.querySelectorAll("[data-item]");

    [].forEach.call(itemsTwo,
        function (itemTwo) {
            itemTwo.addEventListener("click", function (c) {
                c.preventDefault();
                cartlistTwo.value += `\n${itemTwo.innerHTML}`;
            });
        });
});
```

Example of html

```
<div class="row">
        <div id="PollutionPreventionDivScrollDisplay" class="col-md-12 border-colour fixed-height">
            @foreach (var info in Model.EnvironmentalActionPollutionPreventionExtraInfo)
            {
                var countItems = counter++;
                <p><a data-item="@countItems" href="#">@info</a></p>
            }
        </div>
    </div>  

 <div class="col-md-4 border-colour-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="mouse-pointer text-danger" id="PollutionPreventionDivScroll">Click to add options</span>
                <label class="sr-only" for="EnvironmentalActionPollutionPreventionIdeasForActionPlaceholder">Environmental Action Pollution Prevention Ideas For Action</label>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.EnvironmentalActionPollutionPreventionIdeasForAction, new { Class = "form-control", Placeholder = Model.EnvironmentalActionPollutionPreventionIdeasForActionPlaceholder, rows = "8" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

All other code is the same except the sames are different

Answer (score 0):

Ok silly mistake, I had all 'data-item' the same should have been 'data-item-one', 'data-item-two' etc